# React:How to Select All/UnSelect All checkboxes on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying data in the checkboxlist. How to implement Select All and UnselectAll buttons that selects all or unselect all checkboxes. Please find my react code and data coming from api.

[ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” },
{"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]

```
import React from "react";

export class Delete_Item extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) ;          
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          Template_ID: "",
          TemplateName: "",
       Templatelist: [],
      checkedItems: [],
};
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       }

       componentDidMount() {
  this.getTemplateList();
       }

       getTemplateList() {
              fetch(REQUEST_URL, { credentials: 'include' })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                  .then((data) => {
                         this.setState({
                                  Templatelist: data,
                                  TemplateName: data[0].templateName,
                                  loading: false
                           })
                           console.log(this.state.Templatelist);
                     })
       }

       handleChange(event) {
              const id = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);
              const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
              const updatedArray = [...this.state.checkedItems];
              if (index !== -1) {
                     updatedArray.splice(index, 1);
              } else {
                     updatedArray.push(id);
              }
              this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    checkedItems: updatedArray
              }));
              console.log(this.state.checkedItems);
       }
       render() {
              return (
       <div>
 <ul style={{ listStyle: 'none' }} >

     {
(this.state.Templatelist.map((item, index) => {
return (
<li key={item.templateID}>
<input type="checkbox" id={item.templateID} value={item.templateName} 
onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                                                                                &nbsp; {item.templateName}</li>)}))}</ul>

       &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="SelectAll" value="Select All" />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="UnSelectAll" value="Clear All" />
</div>
);
}
}

export default Delete_Item;
```

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select all checkboxes in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888214/how-to-select-all-checkboxes-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

```
selectAll() {
  return this.setState({ checkedItems: this.state.Templatelist.map(id => id) });
}
unselectAll() {
  return this.setState({ checkedItems: [] });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Currently Select All/Unselectall buttons are not working. Its giving the eror: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Are you using an arrow function for the handlers (or binding)? 
`<input type="button" name="SelectAll" value="Select All" onClick={() => selectAll()} />`

Comment: I can help you add a codesandbox

Comment: Hi Roy, Please find the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-gianmarco-uunbxh.  WebApi returns data in this format                                          
[ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]

Comment: I think you need to save the sandbox, it's very empty 

Comment: WebApi returns data in this format [ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]  Please find the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-pond-07qnue

Comment: HI Roy,Please find my updated sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-pond-07qnue. Api returns json data [ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }] . This data is showing as a checkboxlist. Please help how to selectall and clearall checkboxes.

Comment: HI Roy,Please find my updated sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-pond-07qnue. This data is showing as a checkboxlist. Buttons selectall and clearall checkboxes are not working. Please help.

Comment: I forked your example, fixed it and added some suggestions to keep the code clean. Some notes about this: It's easier to store the id's in an object than an array, because you don't need to loop to find an entry. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-firefly-zxeylk?file=/src/Delete_Item.js

(Sorry for the late reply!)